I need help making a cartoony rubber/slime-like material
I want to replicate the same material/effect as the little guy in the GIF below. I’ve tried layer weight nodes but I need the light to as if “remove” the darker color of the character and add more of the fresnel.

Hello, it's not clear what you mean by "but I need the light to as if “remove” the darker color of the character and add more of the fresnel", could you please elaborate?

Do you perhaps mean a translucency effect?

@moonboots so basically when you use the layer weight node and add a light to the scene, it doesn’t effect the colors, only the object. I want the colors to warp around the light when it hits the object.

I believe I've mimicked the look fairly well. Using a Principled BSDF shader as the base:

Set the Base Color as desired.
Set the Roughness to something low (I chose 0.2).
Turn the Subsurface Weight all the way up.
Set the Subsurface Scale very high (I chose 0.8 m).
Set the Specular Tint to match the Base Color.

This is my resulting node setup:

This is how it looks on Subdivision Surface smooth-shaded Suzanne:

Hope this helps!
S.D.G.
